# WAMP reinstalled but login error #1045

Tags: authentication, wamp, reinstall

Newbie here

Installed Wampserver2.4-x64 on Windows 7
MySQL v. 5.5.32
FatCow host
Firefox Browser

My previous install of WAMP was uninstalled over a year ago. With new WAMP install, and new database created on my host's server with login and password, I am still not able to login. The old username is still remembered by my browser, but I don't think that matters. The answers I find on Stack Overflow and in other places show php code from the config file that does not match what I see. I don't know php and don't want to mess anything up.
How do I get my new login info accepted at localhost/phpmyadmin?

My config.inc file contains:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you did not install the new version ov er the old version.

The default login for a new install of MYSQL is

```
username = root
password = (leave this blank )
```

MySQL is delivered with one user account pre loaded called 'root' and it has no password set.